# Function that works as assignment too - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, function, class

How can I make a function in a class able to support this :
(kinda assignment)

```
dim ko as integer = cell(x,y)
```

**AND**

```
cell(c,y) = 3
```

kindest regards,
adoloul

Comment: It's unclear why you would need this, but you can use a [**Property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzh9ha57.aspx) or a 2D array depending on what you need it for.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

***NOTA** : this works in vb, for sure, but ur turn to verify in ur language

Ok nope don't search anymore, I fund using dotnotpearls

I have to use a property with setters and getters

```
Public Property cell(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Integer
    Get
        Return cells(x, y)
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        cells(x, y) = value
    End Set
End Property
```

- don't remove the post, 'should be usefull for anyone!

;)

Comment: This is called a 'parameterized property' and is not available in most languages, so if anyone else is looking at your code you should provide a comment to avoid confusion.